# Authorize request getToken JWT with spring boot 2 and web security 5

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I migrated my spring boot to version 2. Unfortunately, my management methods to authorize does not seem to work anymore.
I can not use the / getToken method without getting a 403 error. this method is essential because it allows me to authenticate the users and therefore to know if they have the authorization to access the resources

Does anyone know what change it would take to make it work again?

here my configuration

```
package restService.serv.api.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Value("${declasin.userName}")
  private String username;

  @Value("${declasin.password}")
  private String password;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/notConnected/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/notConnected/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v2/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui.html**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/services/export/green-card/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/services/export/green-card/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/getToken").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

            // We filter the api/login requests
            http.addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/getToken", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Create a default account

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(username)
            .password(password)
            .roles("ADMIN");
  }
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/getToken")
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/",
                    "/*.html",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js"
            );
  }
  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
  }
}
```

and here my login filter :

```
    public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


      public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
      }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
      HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper()
        .readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            creds.getUsername(),
            creds.getPassword(),
            Collections.emptyList()
        )
    );
  }
```

**EDIT :** 
after having tested the different service to authorize I noticed that it blocks only on / gettoken. The webconfig security looks good.
The transition from spring boot 1.5 to 2.0 has changed some things about the generation service token jwt.

Thx you for your help

Comment: I see "/getToken" being added as authenticationManager and also you are trying to add same in ignore configuration ...     ?? Why so

Comment: I put it here to test, but it did not give a result.